# How to compute how many elements in three arrays in python are equal to some value in the same positon betweel the arrays?

Tags: numpy

I have three numpy arrays

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 1, 7, 3, 9]
c = [10, 1, 3, 3, 1]
```

and i wanna to compute how many elements in a, b, c are equal to 3 in the same position, so for that example would be 3.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution is to use *Numpy* functions, like:

```
np.count_nonzero(np.vstack([a, b, c])==3, axis=0).max()
```

Details:

- `np.vstack([a, b, c])` - generate an array with 3 rows, composed of your
  3 source arrays.
- `np.count_nonzero(...==3, axis=0)` - count how many values of *3* occurs
  in each column. For your data the result is `array([0, 0, 1, 3, 0], dtype=int64)`.
- `max()` - take the greatest value, in your case `3`.